# Compare word within words in java

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

Basically I've:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
String genre = "Action, Animation, Comdey";
String[] genres   = genre.split(", ");
for(int i=0;i<(genres.length)-1;i++){
    System.out.println(genres[i]);
    if(!genres[i].equals("Action")              || !genres[i].equals("Adventure")
            || !genres[i].equals("Animation")   || !genres[i].equals("Biography")
            || !genres[i].equals("Comedy")      || !genres[i].equals("Crime")
            || !genres[i].equals("Documentary") || !genres[i].equals("Drama")
            || !genres[i].equals("Family")      || !genres[i].equals("Fantasy")
            || !genres[i].equals("Film-Noir")   || !genres[i].equals("Game-Show")
            || !genres[i].equals("History")     || !genres[i].equals("Horror")
            || !genres[i].equals("Music")       || !genres[i].equals("Musical")
            || !genres[i].equals("Mystery")     || !genres[i].equals("News")
            || !genres[i].equals("Reality-TV")  || !genres[i].equals("Sci-Fi")
            || !genres[i].equals("Sport")       || !genres[i].equals("Talk-Show")
            || !genres[i].equals("Thriller")    || !genres[i].equals("War")
            || !genres[i].equals("Western")
            ){
        System.out.println("Selected genres could not be identified");
        return;
   }else {
        System.out.println("Success");
   }
}
}
```

As you can see I have a string `genre` which contains `Action, Animation, Comdey`, Then I'm splitting each Word with `,(space)` And Then using `if()` I'm comparing each array. As you might know my arrays which are `Action`, `Animation` and `Comedy` Exists in my `if()` Words list. So it is not suppose to execute `System.out.println("Selected genres could not be identified");` but it does, I don't know why But this is really freaking me out.

You can copy/paste my code at https://www.compilejava.net/ and see the result by yourself.

I would really appreciate if you tell me what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change all the ORs (`||`) to ANDs (`&&`) if you are trying to check that the current genre matches `none` of the available genres, e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String genre = "Action, Animation, Comdey";
    String[] genres = genre.split(", ");
    for (int i = 0; i < (genres.length) - 1; i++) {
        System.out.println(genres[i]);
        if (!genres[i].equals("Action") && !genres[i].equals("Adventure") && !genres[i].equals("Animation")
                && !genres[i].equals("Biography") && !genres[i].equals("Comedy") && !genres[i].equals("Crime")
                && !genres[i].equals("Documentary") && !genres[i].equals("Drama") && !genres[i].equals("Family")
                && !genres[i].equals("Fantasy") && !genres[i].equals("Film-Noir") && !genres[i].equals("Game-Show")
                && !genres[i].equals("History") && !genres[i].equals("Horror") && !genres[i].equals("Music")
                && !genres[i].equals("Musical") && !genres[i].equals("Mystery") && !genres[i].equals("News")
                && !genres[i].equals("Reality-TV") && !genres[i].equals("Sci-Fi") && !genres[i].equals("Sport")
                && !genres[i].equals("Talk-Show") && !genres[i].equals("Thriller") && !genres[i].equals("War")
                && !genres[i].equals("Western")) {
            System.out.println("Selected genres could not be identified");
            return;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Success");
        }
    }
}
```

[Here](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/45.html)'s a bit more on logical `OR` operator. In your scenario, `!genres[i].equals("Action")` evaluates to `false` for 'Action', however, other conditions like `!genres[i].equals("Adventure")` evaluate to `true` and hence, it prints "Selected genres could not be identified".

Comment: Couldn't you just remove the `!` operator instead?

Comment: @Abhijith tried removing `!` and it produces same output as the one mentioned by OP in the question.

Comment: @darshanMehta Which that mean I squandered my whole day trying to figure out what am I doing wrong, Anyways worked thousand thanks.

Comment: @DarshanMehta I meant remove the not operator **& switch the if/else block statements**...

Answer (score 0):

String genre = "Action, Animation, Comdey" should be changed to String genre = "Action, Animation, Comedy"

Comment: That is fine I had it as `Comedy` in my actual string, just mispelled it posting here.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaner and efficient way to write above mentioned code would be using TreeSet:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   String genre = "Action, Animation, Comdey";
    String[] genres = genre.split(", ");
    Set<String> genreSet = new TreeSet<String>();
    genreSet.add("Action");
    genreSet.add("Adventure");
    genreSet.add("Animation");
    genreSet.add("Documentary");
    genreSet.add("Comedy");
    //more genres follows here

    for (int i = 0; i < (genres.length) - 1; i++) {
        System.out.println(genres[i]);
        if (!genreSet.contains(genres[i])) {
            System.out.println("Selected genres could not be identified");
            return;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Success");
        }
  }
  }
```

Efficient because the time complexity for searching genre string in the TreeSet would be in an order of (log n).